# How to update jsonResponse [Struts2 + Ajax + Json]

Tags: json, ajax, struts2

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
 <html>
<head>
<title>AJAX in Struts 2 using JSON and jQuery</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#country').change(function(event) {

    var country = $("select#country").val();
    delete {countryName : country};
    $.getJSON('ajaxAction', {
        countryName : country
    }, function(jsonResponse) {
        $('#ajaxResponse').text(jsonResponse.dummyMsg);
        var select = $('#states');
        select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(jsonResponse.stateMap, function(key, value) {
            $('<option>').val(key).text(value).appendTo(select);
        });
    });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>AJAX calls to Struts 2 using JSON and jQuery</h3>
<s:select id="country" name="country"
    list="{'Select Country','India','US'}" label="Select Country" />
<br />
<br />
<s:select id="states" name="states" list="{'Select State'}"
    label="Select State" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="ajaxResponse"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
 <package name="default" extends="json-default">
    <action name="ajaxAction" class="com.action.AjaxJsonAction">
        <result type="json">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**AjaxJsonAction.java**

```
package com.action;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class AjaxJsonAction implements Action{

    private Map<String, String> stateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    private String dummyMsg;
    //Parameter for Jquery
    private String countryName;

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(countryName);
        if (countryName.equals("India")) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            stateMap.put("1", "Kerala");
            stateMap.put("2", "Tamil Nadu");
            stateMap.put("3", "Jammu Kashmir");
            stateMap.put("4", "Assam");
        } else if (countryName.equals("US")) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            stateMap.put("1", "Georgia");
            stateMap.put("2", "Utah");
            stateMap.put("3", "Texas");
            stateMap.put("4", "New Jersey");
        } else if (countryName.equals("Select Country")) {
            stateMap.put("1", "Select State");
        }
        dummyMsg = "Ajax action Triggered";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getStateMap() {
        return stateMap;
    }

    public String getDummyMsg() {
        return dummyMsg;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setStateMap(Map<String, String> stateMap) {
        this.stateMap = stateMap;
    }

    public void setDummyMsg(String dummyMsg) {
        this.dummyMsg = dummyMsg;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
}
```

When I run above code for the first time and select "India" from dropdown the output is as below:
In Console I get below Output:

```
India  
Hello
```

and in Web UI for "Select Country":"India" below States are showed in "Select State" dropdown :

```
Kerala  
Tamil Nadu  
Jammu Kashmir 
Assam
```

Now I'm changing **AjaxJsonAction.java** and adding **stateMap.put("5", "Odisha");** as below and running it for second time:

```
package com.action;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;

public class AjaxJsonAction implements Action{

    private Map<String, String> stateMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    private String dummyMsg;
    //Parameter for Jquery
    private String countryName;

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println(countryName);
        if (countryName.equals("India")) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            stateMap.put("1", "Kerala");
            stateMap.put("2", "Tamil Nadu");
            stateMap.put("3", "Jammu Kashmir");
            stateMap.put("4", "Assam");
            stateMap.put("5", "Odisha");          //Newly added State
        } else if (countryName.equals("US")) {
            System.out.println("hello");
            stateMap.put("1", "Georgia");
            stateMap.put("2", "Utah");
            stateMap.put("3", "Texas");
            stateMap.put("4", "New Jersey");
        } else if (countryName.equals("Select Country")) {
            stateMap.put("1", "Select State");
        }
        dummyMsg = "Ajax action Triggered";
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getStateMap() {
        return stateMap;
    }

    public String getDummyMsg() {
        return dummyMsg;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public void setStateMap(Map<String, String> stateMap) {
        this.stateMap = stateMap;
    }

    public void setDummyMsg(String dummyMsg) {
        this.dummyMsg = dummyMsg;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
}
```

Second time I don't get any console output if I select "India" from dropdown.

and in Web UI for "Select Country":"India" below States are showed in "Select State" dropdown (same as previous time):

```
Kerala  
Tamil Nadu  
Jammu Kashmir 
Assam
```

Why there's no console output and State "Odisha" is not getting added and what is the correct way to add it?

Comment: `<result type="json">`[`/index.jsp`](http://new2.fjcdn.com/thumbnails/comments/I+think+im+a+little+blue+_1e71c3e1dc954be28dd2ed2c92981b69.png)`</result>` ?

Comment: @Andrea Ligios : I didn't quite understand what you wanted to say.

Comment: A result of type `json` can't return any jsp

Comment: @AndreaLigios : But it did return in my case. If it didn't then it wouldn't run for the first time also. Could you please suggest me any code changeover to do the update.

Comment: Probably some deployment error. Clean rebuild deploy.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: Just a hint, you can use struts 2 jquery plugin that can do this for you with no js code...

Comment: @RomanC yes for sure I'm using Eclipse. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi Let me try the struts 2 jquery plugin and get back to you.

Comment: @RomanC Your question itself solved my problem. I ran the same code in chrome browser instead of eclipse and it worked like a miracle to me.